# Handling Async Function Arguments in Rust Generic Functions

Tags: asynchronous, generics, rust

I am attempting to pass an async function, which I defined in a module of my binary application, as an argument to a generic function that I'm developing within the same Rust application.

The generic function is structured as follows:

```rust
pub async fn listen_for_messages<T: Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Debug + Send + Sync, F, Fut>(
    consumer: Consumer,
    callback: F,
) where
    F: Fn(&T) -> Fut + Sync + Send,
    Fut: Future<Output=()> + Send,
{
    consumer.set_delegate(move |delivery: DeliveryResult| async move {
        let string_date_ini = current_formatted_datetime();
        match delivery {
            Ok(Some(delivery)) => {
                let data = std::str::from_utf8(&delivery.data).unwrap().to_owned();

                match serde_json::from_str::<T>(&data) {
                    Ok(json_data) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} | {} {:?}",
                            string_date_ini,
                            "Received this message:".yellow(),
                            json_data
                        );
                        callback(&json_data).await;
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("{} {:?}", "Error parsing JSON:".red(), err);
                    }
                }
                // Confirma a recepção da mensagem
                let _ = delivery.ack(BasicAckOptions::default()).await;
            }
            Ok(None) => println!("{} | {}", string_date_ini, "Consumer was canceled.".red()),
            Err(error) => println!(
                "{} | {} {:?}",
                string_date_ini,
                "Error:".red().bold(),
                error
            ),
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to call it like this:

```rust
queue::my_module::listen_for_messages::<queue::callback::My_Type, _, _>(
        consumer,
        queue::callback::handle_text_sent,
    )
    .await;
```

And the async function definition looks like this:

```rust
pub async fn handle_text_sent(rabbitmq_message: &'_ RabbitMQMessage)
```

I've also experimented with passing the function as a reference, but continue to encounter errors. Passing it as a reference necessitates specifying a lifetime; however, I am constrained to using 'static', which leads to further issues. Attempting the approach I previously described results in the following error:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
    |
70  |       consumer.set_delegate(move |delivery: DeliveryResult| async move {
    |                ------------ -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                |            |
    |  ______________|____________this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
    | |              |
    | |              required by a bound introduced by this call
71  | |         let string_date_ini = current_formatted_datetime();
72  | |         match delivery {
73  | |             Ok(Some(delivery)) => {
...   |
84  | |                         callback(&json_data).await;
    | |                         -------- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `callback` out of its environment
...   |
100 | |         }
101 | |     });
    | |_____- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

I am seeking to understand the correct method for passing an async function as an argument in this context.

**UPDATE**

I've successfully resolved the issue with passing the callback, thanks to ChrisB's assistance. The generic function now has the following structure:

```rust
pub async fn listen_for_messages<T, F, Fut>(consumer: Consumer, callback: &'static F)
where
    T: Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Debug + Send + Sync,
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut + Sync + Send + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + Send,
{
    consumer.set_delegate(move |delivery: DeliveryResult| async move {
        let string_date_ini = current_formatted_datetime();
        match delivery {
            Ok(Some(delivery)) => {
                let data = std::str::from_utf8(&delivery.data).unwrap().to_owned();

                match serde_json::from_str::<T>(&data) {
                    Ok(json_data) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} | {} {:?}",
                            string_date_ini,
                            "Received this message:".yellow(),
                            json_data
                        );
                        callback(json_data).await;
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("{} {:?}", "Error parsing JSON:".red(), err);
                    }
                }
                // Confirma a recepção da mensagem
                let _ = delivery.ack(BasicAckOptions::default()).await;
            }
            Ok(None) => println!("{} | {}", string_date_ini, "Consumer was canceled.".red()),
            Err(error) => println!(
                "{} | {} {:?}",
                string_date_ini,
                "Error:".red().bold(),
                error
            ),
        }
    });
}
```

In my current solution, I've passed the callback function by reference and altered its signature to clone the JSON data instead of receiving it by reference. However, this approach doesn't align with my ultimate goal. Cloning the JSON data, especially given its large size, is inefficient and unnecessary. Yet, whenever I attempt to pass the JSON data as a reference, I consistently encounter the following error:

```
error: higher-ranked lifetime error
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     queue::rabbitmq::listen_for_messages::<queue::callback::My_Type, _, _>(
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, I need help on how to efficiently pass JSON data by reference to enhance performance. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The callback is now defined as follows:

```rust
pub async fn handle_text_sent(rabbitmq_message: RabbitMQMessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust has three main function traits: `Fn`, `FnOnce` and `FnMut`. More on them [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html).

As the compiler tells you, your closure is a `FnOnce`, meaning it can only be called once. That makes sense, at it `move`s `DeliveryResult` and consumes it during it's execution. If we were to execute it again, where would it get another `DeliveryResult` from?

Your generic function, `listen_for_messages` expects a `Fn` as an argument,
which is a function that can be called an arbitrary amount of times.

Therefore the compiler complains, as the closure does not meet the requirements.

You now have two ways of fixing this:

1. Make your function take a `FnOnce` instead.
2. Don't consume the `DeliveryResult` in your closure, but clone it or use it by reference instead, making your closure satisfy `Fn`.

Either fix should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to clone and it solved the problem that I described:

pub async fn listen_for_messages<'a, T, F, Fut>(
    consumer: Consumer,
    callback: F,
) where
    T: Serialize + DeserializeOwned + Debug + Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: for<'b> Fn(&'b T) -> Fut + Sync + Send  + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'a,
{
    let callback = Arc::new(callback);
    consumer.set_delegate(move |delivery: DeliveryResult| {
        let callback = Arc::clone(&callback);
        async move {
            let string_date_ini = current_formatted_datetime();

Comment: But now, I am have issues with lifetimes:

error: higher-ranked lifetime error
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     queue::rabbitmq::listen_for_messages::<queue::callback::My_Type, _, _>(
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Lemos: glad this helped. If it answered your question, please accept the answer. If you have another question, just ask another SO question :).

Comment: Update for @ChrisB: I am going to update my original post with some new information I've discovered. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take another look and offer your assistance once more. Thank you again for your patience.